# A Documentation edit can’t be approved

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

When I visit [this proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/6749?draftId=6896) and click “Approve,” it shows an error:

[image: An error has occurred during submission; please try again.]

Reloading or trying again doesn’t help.

Comment: Indeed, reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.  Bug around detecting and merging other proposed changes to the same topic.

Comment: It seems the bug is still around http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328883/empty-change-causes-an-error-when-approving-rejecting