# Empty change causes an error when approving/rejecting

Tags: bug, status-norepro, documentation

Take a look at these changes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/21647
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/12918

The diff is empty. When I try to approve or reject it, I get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: I could reject the => vs <=> thingy

Comment: Maybe this was fixed? In any case, both have been handled.